# How to set SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY environment variable in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy a model that i have registered. I registered the model using the following code:

```
step_register = RegisterModel(
    name="RegisterCustomModel",
    estimator=estimator,
    model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
    content_types=["text/csv"],
    response_types=["text/csv"],
    inference_instances=["ml.t2.medium", "ml.m5.large"],
    transform_instances=["ml.m5.large"],
    model_package_group_name=model_package_group_name,
    approval_status=model_approval_status,
    model_metrics=model_metrics,
)
```

However, I am getting an error when i deploy this model which I believe is because the environment variable `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY` is not set.

My question is, can I set the environment variable `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY` in the `RegisterModel` function and if I can, how do I do that?

Comment: you can set environment variables for Model but not RegisterModel. Does it work if you use `Model(env={"SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY":"..."}, ...)`?

Comment: So I tried doing `RegisterModel(env={"SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY":"..."}, ...)` but that didn't work.